# How do I set the selection in a listview?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a listview with a QStringModel and I want to change its to selection programatically. I have a a python list of indices as ints, [1,3,4], that I would like to select. How can I select these indices? Does the listview have a function that will allow me to select a row?

Comment: Have you tried setSelection method from listview? http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistview.html#setSelection

Comment: Yes, but it will not take a simple python list of indices, like [1,2,3,4]. It requires some other object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out myself, here is the answer, assuming you have a listview "myListview", a corresponding model "myQStringListModel" with at least 6 elements (0-5) and a array of indices [1,3,5]:

```
theIndices = [1,3,5]
theQIndexObjects = [self.myQStringListModel.createIndex(rowIndex, 0, self.coverages_lm) for rowIndex in theIndices]
for Qindex in theQIndexObjects:
    myListview.selectionModel().select(Qindex, QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Select)
```

IMO its not very straight forward that you have to use the model to create an index object, but it makes sense I guess.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you used the QStringListModel not the QStringModel,assume you use the QListView.Here is the code

```
    model = new QStringListModel(this);

listView = new QListView;
listView->setModel(model);
listView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);//you can select many selections;
```