# How to get the index or string of the row selected in the QListView?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview

Not sure how to display the item or index clicked in the list?

```
{
...
    nrow = 10;     
    ncol = 1;

    /*create QListView */
    m_listView = new QListView(this);
    m_listView->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0,100), QSize(100, 150)));
    connect(m_listView, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(hItem()));

    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel( nrow, 1, this );

    //fill model value
    for( int r=0; r<nrow; r++ )
    {
        QString sstr = "[ " + QString::number(r) + " ]";
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString("Idx ") + sstr);
        model->setItem(r, 0, item);
    }
}

void MainWindow::hItem()
{
    m_txt1->setText(item@clicked);
}
```

Comment: You seem to know enough to realize that the signal passes `QModelIndex` as a parameter. Just have your slot actually accept that. `QModelIndex`  has `row()`, `column()` and `data()` methods, among others.

Comment: m_txt1->setText(QString::number(m.row(),'d',0));//WORKS........BUT m_txt2->setText(m.data());//FAILS

Comment: `data()` returns a QVariant. You likely need something like `setText(m.data().toString())`

Comment: Good to know for multiselect:  listView->setSelectionMode( QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection );

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777159/how-do-i-set-the-selection-in-a-listview/15778450#15778450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signal emitted by the `QListView` has a `QModelIndex` object as a parameter.
Edit your slot that it matches the signature of the signal: `void MainWindow::hItem(QModelIndex idx)`.

With your `QModelIndex` object you can retrieve the clicked row by using `column()` or `row()`. See here: http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qmodelindex.html

Comment: m_txt1->setText(QString::number(m.row(),'d',0));//WORKS........BUT  m_txt2->setText(m.data());//FAILS